# What happens to a Luttinger liquid under time reversal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Suppose you a have an ordinary Luttinger liquid with
$$ H = \int dx \sum _{\eta= \pm 1 , \sigma =\uparrow,\downarrow }  \psi^\dagger_{\eta, \sigma} (x) (-i v \eta \partial _x) \psi _{\eta,\sigma} (x). $$

You then bosonize it using 
$$\psi_{\eta,\sigma}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \alpha}} F_{\eta ,\sigma} e^{-i \phi_{\eta, \sigma}}$$
where F is the Klein factor and $\phi$ a bosonic field.

My question is, what happens to F and $\phi$ under time reversal?

The problem here is that the usual result for fermions, 
 $$T c_{i,\uparrow} T^{-1}= c_{i,\downarrow}$$
$$T c_{i,\downarrow} T^{-1}=- c_{i,\uparrow}$$

where T is the time reversal operator, 
is not so obvious when there is separation between the Klein factor and the phase.
I mean, why would $\phi_\uparrow$ turn into $\phi_\downarrow$ ?